# PHP server to receive data from android application

Tags: php, android, json

I am new to the communication side. Was just trying to get some data from an android application periodically.  But somehow its not working.. Have written a php script Do i need to add something more..?
Do i need to add any permission in androidmanifest..?
Also giving my android app code.. It force closes when I click get my location.

PHP script

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, world!';
$json = $_GET['jsonpost'];//get the post you sent...
$data = json_decode($json); //decode the json formatted string...
print_r($data);
$id = $data->id;
$devid = $data->devid;
$latitude = $data->latitude;
$longitude = $data->longitude;
$service = $data->service;
$con = mysql_connect("","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("a5234826_ul", $con);
$devid = $_POST['devid']; 
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
echo "devid" +$devid;
echo "latitude" + $latitude;
echo "longitude" + $longitude; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `a5234826_ul`.`locations` (
`id` ,
`devid` ,
`latitude` ,
`longitude` ,
`service`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '$devid',  '$latitude',  '$longitude', '$service'  
)";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($variable);

?>
```

LocationService.java

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "lock");
wl.acquire();
context = this;
final String who = intent.getStringExtra("who");
final LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener(){

    // start location changed

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        double longitude = loc.getLongitude();


        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://.../serverFile.php");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String devid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

        String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"devid\":\""+devid+"\"}}";




        try {  

            json.put("longitude", longitude);//place each of the strings as you did in postData method
            json.put("latitude", latitude);

            json.put("devid", devid);

            JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
            postjson.put(json);
            httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);     
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // for JSON retrieval:
            if(response != null)
            { 
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            try {
            is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            String jsonStr = sb.toString(); //take the string you built place in a string



            JSONObject rec = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String longitudecord = rec.getString("lon");
                String latitudecord = rec.getString("lat");
            // ...
            }
            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        if (who.equals("me")){
            Intent i = new Intent(context.getPackageName()+".LocationReceived");
            i.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
            i.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
            i.putExtra("accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
            context.sendBroadcast(i);
            Notification notif = new Notification();
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notif.tickerText = "Location Found!";
            notif.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notif.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestLocatorActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(latitude));
            notificationIntent.putExtra("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
            notificationIntent.putExtra("accuracy", String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Location Found!", "Click to open.", contentIntent);
            nm.notify(0, notif);
        } else {
            SmsManager smsMan = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsMan.sendTextMessage(who, null, "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:"+latitude+","+longitude, null, null);
            smsMan.sendTextMessage(who, null, "Latitude: "+latitude+"\nLongitude: "+longitude, null, null);
        }
        locMan.removeUpdates(this);
        try {
            wl.release();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopSelf();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){


    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //Log.i(tag, "GPS IS ON");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        switch(status) {
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                break;
        }
    } };


locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);

return 2;
}

}
```

**One more thing I am trying to get the value of the latitude and longitude fron LocationService class to Post class is the code in Post class right..
Please help me..**

Comment: Have you sent test form data through a browser to see if an error is output by PHP?

Comment: No..But is the code complete for the php server to receive data..?

Comment: It looks like you have all of the necessary parts to me.

Comment: @JohnConde can you help me in the part where i am getting the value of the latitude and longitude from LocationService to Post class... If its right or not..?

Comment: Your PHP looks correct. Your next step should be to send a simulated form submission to that script and see what happens. If there is an error the odds are you'll see it.

Comment: Am I the only one seeing the gaping security hole in the code? Seriously the SQL injection here is trivial.

Comment: @RichardRose: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). Also, don't use $_POST variables directly in queries without any kind of escaping.

Comment: Can you help me with this... Just a lil help..If you dont mind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make a simple script to ensure that you are indeed properly accessing the db. You could just run the script in a browser and that way rule out any connection/access issues to the db:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("dbName");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from TABLENAME where COLUMNNAME like 'searchparameter'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like @Vivek Kumar Srivastava said.

When you use postData your sending it in Json format so on your php end you need to actually decode it...

the code would be like this.

it maybe better to create a JSON object in your android code like this...

As `Vivek Kumar Srivastava` said:

When you use postData your sending it in Json format so on your php end you need to actually decode it.

It may be better to create a JSON object in your android code like below.

```
private postData() throws JSONException{  
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://.../serverFile.php");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

try {           
    json.put("longitude", longitude);//place each of the strings as you did in postData method
    json.put("latitude", latitude);
    json.put("service", service);
    json.put("devid", devid);

    JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
    postjson.put(json);
    post.setHeader("json",json.toString());
    post.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);     
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    // for JSON retrieval:
    if(response != null)
    { 
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    try {
    is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    String jsonStr = sb.toString(); //take the string you built place in a string



    JSONObject rec = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    String longitudecord = rec.getString("lon");
        String latitudecord = rec.getString("lat");
    // ...
    }
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

Now your php code...

```
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];//get the post you sent...
$data = json_decode($json); //decode the json formatted string...
$longitude = $data->longitude;
$latitude = $data->latitude;
$service = $data->service;
$devid = $data->devid;
```

`And then continue with your sql from there on.`
You will encode them into JSON if you want to read them back into Android as shown in the code above...

Comment: Hello thank you for the response.. so i just need to add this in my code..? the PHP part you gave and the java part to Post.java..?

Comment: I just went through your profile.. What your trying to do is to post the lat and long you get from your app to post it on a site.. of php. Could you help me also with that...  please

Comment: So i will just add the code you gave me in the php and the code for android..? you gave..?

Comment: :hey i tried your code... its telling me to put `json.put("longitude", longitude);
json.put("latitude", latitude);
json.put("service", service);
json.put("devid", devid);` in a try catch...? can you mail me your android code part.. if you dont mind..

Comment: If you are using eclipse it will automatically add them if you right click the underlined red text, but if not check my answer, I just edited

Comment: I tried... but its showing me some funny errors... can you send me your code where your posting lats and longs on a web server. showing me error on the **post** word...

Comment: It says **Create a local variable**

Comment: Hey I made changes in the php script and the java file... nothing is getting posted on the site... please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your php code because in Android side data send as a json format like

```
 String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"deviceid\":\""+deviceid+"\"}}"
```

but you directly try to fetch data without decoding json.

So need to first decode your json then fetch the data in specific order

see the below link for more details

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: are u go through with given link

Comment: @inspired's answer is also helpful for you, Please go through with that

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any PHP code to accept `POST` data. I have written similar apps where I send data to the server and record it to the database. I usually have some script where I accept the `POST` data and use the values from that. You must use the `POST` method in Android SDK to send the data to the URL. This is easier than sending the data using `JSON` and then decoding it on the PHP end. If I needs to receive data from the server I return values as `JSON` and then decode it in Android using the SDK.